# cancel a print job in ubuntu 14.04 after using lpq -a?

Tags: printing

I have ubuntu 14.04 and I've send a lot of print jobs to the impress and with the command lpq -a I saw all the jobs send to it. Now I'd like to know how cancel that jobs that are listed in number order

I have all the jobs appearing on my terminal but I would like to cancel all of them. I would like to know how to cancel the jobs cause lpqn its nos worthing it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the job number(s), from `lpq -a` e.g:

```
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)     Total Size
1st     wilf    59      PRINT.pdf   50547712 bytes
```

You should be able to cancel it with the command `cancel` - e.g:

```
cancel 59
```

You may also be the `lprm` command.
See also:

- [cancel manpage](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/man-cancel.html) (should be available locally from `man cancel`)
- [CUPS commands](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/options.html)

Comment: I put the command cancel 53 and it appears:

Comment: I put the command cancel 53 and it appears: cancel job #53 is already complete so I understood I had already canceled that, cause when the cancel command is typed it appears nothing to show that had been deleted. But as I saw that message I understood the aim had been reached. So I kept  my job doing cancel 62 so till I get cancel 67 and nothing appears again so I realized the machine does it job silently.  By trying  cancel 62 twice the message: "cancel job 62 complete can't  cancel" appears.  So then I it just show up. I sent a new job and abracadabra all got well. Thanks for all!!